# PHP create a centralized dispatcher for REST like api

Tags: php, web-services, rest, dispatcher, restful-url

hi i am not sure if this is restful related, i think it is , but please do correct me if i am wrong.
so basically i want my server, which is written in PHP, to respond to different api requests, so for example

```
 http://www.myweb.com/api/content/video/get?id=1 which will return a json object that has information regarding of a video of id=1
```

however, i can also have the following api to be called

```
 http://www.myweb.com/api/content/music/get?name=biever
```

i want to create a centralized dispatcher, a php file that sits in the api directory in the server, so whenever a request is made where api appears in the RESTful link (which is in both example above), it shoudld 'intercept' these requests, and examine rest of the path to call the function accordingly.  so for example

in controller.php in api directory
it will see, oh you are calling content/video, i will do some pre processing (say, adding video name or something) then direct the method call to content/video/get

how can i, in php, make sure that all the requests will go through my controller file first?

Answer (score 0):

By default URLs are mapped to PHP files in your file system. You can't control this *in* PHP. By the time your PHP is run, you're too late. So you'll need to look into rewriting the URL at the webserver-level. If you're using Apache look into mod_rewrite.

Comment: thanks chris for answer. so what is REST like approach? if i don't have  a centralized dispatcher like i desribebed above, does it still count as a REST?